# How would I add an outline / border around this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, sketch-app, outline

I have a **vector** of a few unicorns that is currently on a blue background:

[image]

I want to put them on a white background, but when I do that, the unicorns lose their shape because they are white and don't have an outline:

[image]

How would I add a border / outline to them without having to draw it myself?

I'm looking for methods related to Photoshop, Sketch, or Illustrator.

Comment: Photoshop : Layer Style > Stroke -- Is there something preventing that? Although Sketch (Or Illustrator) would be a better tool for vectors.

Comment: @Scott I have sketch and illustrator too

Comment: Glad I could help. I edited the question to be less application-specific. I don't know Sketch. Someone may provide a method for that app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Illustrator**...

Group the Unicorn if it's not already a group.

Then in the **Appearance Panel** add a new stroke to the *group*. Click and drag the stroke 
in the Appearance Panel, so that it is **below** the `<Contents>` item in the panel.

[image]

You'll then have a stroke around the entire group which you can adjust.

<sub>(Old screenshot... but the panel isn't really that different today.)</sub>

---

**Photoshop** : `Layer Style > Stroke` will add a stroke around an entire layer or smart object layer. Although, for vectors using Illustrator or Sketch is probably better.

Comment: This worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

I think this is not possible, because the border of the unicorn is white in color and cannot be white. You can find places that offer unicorn images with black borders.