# how to make the outline pass only outside the shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, outline

on illustrator
I would like to have only one outline that would be outside, I cannot merge otherwise the colors will not be different and I tried to create an outline by duplicating the shape behind but the problem is that it works behind the other shape which is on the right

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119266/how-would-i-add-an-outline-border-around-this-image/119269#119269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this involves organising your artwork into groups with objects in the stack layered in the correct order, and separating the stroke from the filled objects as a separate object with no fill and only a stroke.

Anyway, here's how it could be done

Set no stroke on the yellow filled objects. Then copy and paste in place the objects that make up the entire yellow shape, do a pathfinder Unite on those objects. Set its fill to none, set the stroke to black. Group all the artwork.  Now if you make copies of the group, this way, the stroke will always be on top. In the example below, notice that inside the group stack, the Black Outline is at the top.

Anything else, like a shadow for example, can go in between the groups. In the example below I have the shadow in a clip group. The shadow object has a multiply mode applied to the fill in the Appearance panel . I can move the shadow and top group around by selecting them in the layers panel.

An example

[image]

Comment: yes it's logical I don't know I confused my brain, you have to do the outlines before using the pathfinder, now I know, thank you very much!